# Filtro en Base de datos sin palabras especificas C# y SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo una aplicacion que realiza busqueda en la base de datos de acuerdo a un parametro(caja de texto), el problema radica en que quiero omitir las busquedas con palabras `S.A de C.V`, `sa de cv`, `s.a. de` etc..

Para hacer eso realice una pequeña funcion que verifique si la cadena contiene cierta palabra, el detalle esque tengo que hacer bastantes comprobaciones...

habrá alguna manera de realizar este proceso sin tantas comparaciones ?

```
public bool cadenaValida(string strCadena)
    {
        bool bolvalor;

        if (strCadena.Contains("%") || strCadena.Contains("sa de cv") || strCadena.Contains("SA de CV") || strCadena.Contains("S.A. de C.V."))
            bolvalor = false;
        else
            bolvalor = true;

        return bolvalor;
    }
```

Comment: Si, gracias por la observacion

Comment: Lo puees hacer con un foreach o con un switch, pero no te vas a salvar de poner todas las variables  u opciones de entrada, otra cosa importante es que compare los strings ya sea todo en mayúsculas o todo en minúsculas, .toUpper()

Comment: A ver si no quieres lanzar un query con esas palabras o símbolos, porque no simplemente le pones el .Replace("%","") para cada caso y si la cadena restante queda con mas de 1 carácter lanza la consulta al SQL, me parece muy tonto que el usuario ponga "Empresa patito sa de cv" y que el sistema le diga NO ES VALIDO, pues nomas quitale la parte no valida y busca  "Empresa patito"... y si la cadena de busquesda queda vacía después del replace pues no busques nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más sencillo que puedes hacer es declarar una lista con las palabras que desees buscar, iterar dicha lista y validar uno a uno que el valor de la lista esté contenido en tu cadena de entrada, en el primer valor encontrado se rompe el ciclo y regresará un `true`.

```
public bool cadenaValida(string strCadena)
{
    bool bolvalor = false;
    //strCadena = "SELECT 'SA DE CV' %";

    List<string> words = new List<string>();

    words.Add("%");
    words.Add("sa de cv");
    words.Add("SA DE CV");
    words.Add("S.A. de C.V.");

    foreach (var item in words)
    {
        if (strCadena.ToUpper().Contains(item.ToUpper())){
            bolvalor= true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return bolvalor;
}
```

Comment: yo le agregaria .toUpper.... al strCadena y a item

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo gracias por la observación ;)

Comment: de nada, si estaría bien ponerla, yo la hago casi siempre, porque no sabes que tipo de datos agregara el usuario... Gracias.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Me ha servido de mucho!